# Spring boot project .war file DONT start automatically after deploying in web-apps folder

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, deployment, web-applications

I implemented a spring boot project with .war as packaging. And I deploy it to a server inside of web-apps folder.

> What have i do that the spring-project.war will automatically start after deploying to web-apps folder?

Are there any maven tricks within the pom.xml?

> After push it on git to master branch, the spring boot project will automatically package using `mvn clean package -P war` and after that the .war file will deploy to the web-apps folder. but it do not start automatically.

Thanks guys for helping me.

**My application main starter class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SeminarbuchungApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SeminarbuchungApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SeminarbuchungApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.portsol19</groupId>
    <artifactId>seminarbuchung</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>seminarbuchung</name>
    <description>Seminarservices for Seminarbuchung</description>

    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>int</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>int</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jar</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>war</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is significant about the war file being deployed to the `web-apps` folder? Do you have something watching that directory that you expect to notice the new file and do something with it? Can you describe that part of things in your question please.

Comment: I have a little tomcat server with some spring mvc apps. When i deploy them as a war file to the web-apps folder, the app is automatically startet.

With that project its not possible. I have to start it via **mvn spring-boot:run**

Comment: Thanks. Just to double-check, I assume that `web-apps` is a typo as Tomcat's folder is named `webapps`. What, if anything appears in Tomcat's log files when the file is deployed?

Comment: For starters fix your dependencies, they are a mess. YOu are mixing jars from Spring BOot 2.1 and 2.2 and an additional Spring version. That is trouble waiting to happen. Also use the starter for Elastichsearch so that you get a compatible version.